# Bootstrap Modal closes when button pressed using Ipad?

Tags: asp.net, ipad, twitter-bootstrap-3, bootstrap-modal

Im using Boostrap 3 where i have a modal popup. Inside that modal popup is a submit button.

On the desktop it works fine (modal stays up) but if im viewing via an ipad then the modal popup is closed after the submit button is pressed.

Any ideas on why this would be or any suggestions?

I have the page setup, if you click the subscribe link it will bring up the modal.

Answer (score 0):

The postback code was running. I ended up calling this from code behind to show the modal popup

```
ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this.Page, this.GetType(), "script", "SubscribePopup();", true);
```

and having this javascript code

```
 function SubscribePopup () {
    $('#Subscribe').modal('show');
    return true;
};
```